# How to denote an inner singleton in Scala

Tags: scala, oop, singleton, inner-classes

To exercise my OOP abilities on Scala-specific features, I have tried to design a game where I have a `Player` class. It has an abstract method `play` which decides, given a list of players (different from the player the method is called on), what action to take. I wanted to prevent the `play` method to alter the state of this other players. The right way to play is to cast a `Spell` and let the system reflect its effect on other players.

Yet, the `play` method needs read access to the other players to decide a strategy. I have thus created an inner singleton `ReadOnlyPlayer`. I made it a singleton to prevent copying over and over and simply returning this singleton everytime.

```
abstract class Player(private var _health: Int = 0) {
    Check.isPositive(_health)

    def health = _health

    def play(players: List[/*?*/]) // how to denote inner type ReadOnlyPlayer ?

    def hit(damage: Int) = { _health = max(0, _health - damage); this }

    def safeCopy = ReadOnlyPlayer

    final object ReadOnlyPlayer extends Player {
        override def health = _health

        // noop
        override def hit (damage: Int  ) = this
        override def play(players: List[/*?*/]) = ()
    }
}
```

I can't get it to compile because of the line I put a comment on. I am aware of a number of workarounds to this issue :

- if it was a class instead of a singleton, I could use `Player#ReadOnlyPlayer`. I tried, it works fine. However, this requires to create a new copy everytime, so if I wanted to do this it would actually be better to create a separate immutable class.
- I could manually implement a singleton pattern and always return the same instance of this class.
- I could make the class private and only declare `Player`, but I want my clients to know they explicitly know they won't be able to modify the `Player` instance. I can do this using an sealed empty trait with a meaningful name.

I know how I can handle this in various ways, so my question is more out of curiosity : **how can one denote an inner singleton type ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I'm answering without fully understanding what you're trying to do making a list of inner singletons.

Typically the type of a singleton is accessed by using `SingletonName.type`. So, in your case, it would look like this:

```
abstract class Player(private var _health: Int = 0) {

  def health = _health

  def play(players: List[ReadOnlyPlayer.type]) = ()// how to denote inner type ReadOnlyPlayer ?

  def hit(damage: Int) = { _health = Math.max(0, _health - damage); this }

  def safeCopy = ReadOnlyPlayer

  final object ReadOnlyPlayer extends Player {
    override def health = _health

    // noop
    override def hit (damage: Int  ) = this
    override def play(players: List[ReadOnlyPlayer.type]) = ()
  }
}
```

Comment: Works indeed. Could you extend a bit on this ? I did not know this even existed

Comment: This actually compiles but does not work for this design, since this type is tied to the particular instance of `Player` on which the method is called. I think I am going to stick with my third solution. Is there nothing comparable to `Outer#Inner` when `Inner` is a singleton instead of a class ?

Comment: (1) Sure thing, a singleton is by definition the only object of its type, so its type signature is not its name, but must be accessed via .type, (2) I'm afraid not, since, extending from (1) each singleton will be object specific and thus "tied" as you say, so a list of inner singletons does not make much sense. If your goal is to make a read only copies of the player, I would say that the new copy way is the best + idiomatic. If you must avoid lots of copies of read only players,  something like this may help (again, just an example): https://gist.github.com/lloydmeta/e947a8f19b9edb585e6c

Comment: Accepting your answer, and posting my final design. Do you have an opinion on it, as a subquestion ?

Comment: I don't think it differs a lot from what you proposed but if you prefer one of them I would be interested to know why

Comment: Between to two of them, I think I like yours more :D; the only thing I would do is put the noop overrides into the definition of the ReadOnlyPlayer, since those behaviours are universal across all objects of that type. In general though, I tend to stay away from mutable data since it's non-idiomatic and somewhat hard to reasonable, but I don't have a background in games programming, where I hear that is the norm :)

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't have a background either, I was just looking a complex enough design problem to try out the OOP aspect of Scala since I mainly explored the functional aspect. MMO-like games are an interesting challenge in this regard. Anyway, thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

As @lloydme pointed it, what I was trying to achieve didn't really make sense. Here is the solution I finally opted for :

```
sealed trait ReadOnlyPlayer extends Player

abstract class Player(private var _health: Int = 0) {
    Check.isPositive(_health)

    def health = _health

    def play(players: List[ReadOnlyPlayer])

    def hit(damage: Int) = { _health = max(0, _health - damage); this }

    lazy val safeCopy: ReadOnlyPlayer = ReadOnlyCopy

    private object ReadOnlyCopy extends ReadOnlyPlayer {
        override def health = _health

        // noop
        override def hit (damage: Int) = this
        override def play(players: List[ReadOnlyPlayer]) = ()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A list of nested objects:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_60).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> class X(id: Int) { object Y { def y = id } }
defined class X

scala> val xs = List.tabulate(10)(new X(_))
xs: List[X] = List(X@5f77d0f9, X@463fd068, X@895e367, X@1b266842, X@7a3793c7, X@42b3b079, X@651aed93, X@4dd6fd0a, X@bb9e6dc, X@5456afaa)

scala> val Ys = xs map (_.Y)
Ys: List[x$1.Y.type forSome { val x$1: X }] = List(X$Y$@43c67247, X$Y$@fac80, X$Y$@726386ed, X$Y$@649f2009, X$Y$@14bb2297, X$Y$@69adf72c, X$Y$@797501a, X$Y$@1a15b789, X$Y$@57f791c6, X$Y$@51650883)

scala> val ys = Ys map (_.y)
ys: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I don't think this fully addresses the question, which is to know how to refer to the type of the inner object so that I can pass a list of `ReadOnlyPlayer` singletons from different outer `Player` instances. From the other answer, it looks that it's impossible because all of these types are specific to each instance. Hence the use of a trait extended by the inner object

Comment: The list of `Ys` all have different outer instances of `X`. The existential type expresses that the `x` value is unknown.

Comment: Yeah I noticed this weird `forSome` :D I'll make some experiments with it outside of the interpreter